# What does key word acme means in hyperledger composer namespaces?

Tags: namespaces, hyperledger, hyperledger-composer

In every user-defined namespace there is this word acme like 
org.acme.shipping.perishable

what does this keyword mean?

Answer (score 4):

It's not a keyword. See
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Acme_Corporation

you could replace 'acme' with 'mycompany' for example

Comment: I've been grumbling about org.acme for a while as well- I've opened an issue to use something more sensible https://github.com/hyperledger/composer/issues/2662

Answer (score 0):

acme Freight is an imaginary logistic company.[IBM's micro-services](https://acme-freight.mybluemix.net/) architecture uses it frequently to demonstrate it's capabilities.It's not a keyword and in place of org.acme you can replace your own organisation.

Use [Visual studio code](https://code.visualstudio.com/) and composer extension to recognize key words(key words in composer are usually rendered yellow in vscode IDE;can be customized though)

Answer (score 0):

It's not a keyword. It's a **convention to define your package name**. Hyperledger has defined examples with a company named as acme.

We do follow similar convention in Java. For an instance, suppose you are developing some solution for StackOverflow having a **domain name as stackoverflow.com**, the package name would be **com.stackoverflow.***.

Hope this helps.